# Replace node using XML:LibXML

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

I am trying to replace some nodes value in XML using the `XML:LibXML` file parser from user input.

Example XML:

```
<header>
   <id x_id="1">
      <a>NA</a>
      <b>NA</b>
      <c>NA</c>
   </id>
</header>
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

print "Please specify node b content\n";
my $node_b = <STDIN>;
chomp $node_b;

my $template = "xx.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($template);
my($object0) = $doc->findnodes("/header/id/b/text()");
my $text0 = XML::LibXML::Text->new($node_b);
$object0->replaceNode($text0);
```

Currently my code is working, but it somehow removed `</a>` from the xml when I tried to replace Node b content. And, when trying to replace node c, `</a>` and `</b>` got removed as well.

Comment: And if you replace `</a>NA</a>` with `<a>NA</a>` (etc), your code works, although you don't do anything with the modified document, such as saving it to disk. Is this question about the missing call to `$doc->toFile`?

Comment: @Blurman -- provided data are not complaint with [XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) standards. You should use `<a>data</a>` to correct the issue. You can use following form `<img href="/some/path/image.png" />` tags to storing data (`<a data="some text" />`). I wold suggest to read following [Perl XML::LibXML by Example](https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) document which will give you great start.

Comment: @ikegami, my code works but somehow it removed </a> when I was trying to replace <b>x</b> node content. No problem on calling the file.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if you could provide your code as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can just copy and run.

That said, this works for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'XML');
<header>
   <id x_id="1">
      <a>A</a>
      <b>B</b>
      <c>C</c>
   </id>
</header>
XML

my ($object0) = $doc->findnodes("/header/id/b");
if ($object0) {
   $object0->replaceNode(XML::LibXML::Text->new("replaced"));
}
else {
   ($object0) = $doc->findnodes("/header/id/b");
   my $node = XML::LibXML::Element->new("B");
   $node->addChild(XML::LibXML::Text->new("new text"));
   $object0->replaceNode($node);
}
print STDERR "$doc\n";
```

It prints

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<header>
   <id x_id="1">
      <a>A</a>
      <b>replaced</b>
      <c>C</c>
   </id>
</header>
```

Comment: may i know which version of perl you using?

Comment: I realized when there is value in node a, the code works fine. But when node a is empty, '<a></a>' , then the code will remove </a> . Any idea why this happen?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me. Only if `<b>` is empty, it doesn't find the `text()` and errors out. You can get around that by just looking for `<b>`, and when you find it, check whether it has text content or not. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Can you try to remove A in node a but retain <a></a> and run your script?

Comment: it's fine as I realized changing from <a></a> to <a/> does not really affect my next step. However, not sure whether you know how to edit value in x_id? Let say change from 1 to 2?

Comment: You'd find the node (as before, just without the `text()`), then `$node->attributes` gives you the list of its attributes. Add, remove, replace as needed.